# Four fair coins are repeatedly tossed simultaneously until all four show the same face. What is the probability that this occurs on the fourth toss?

Tags: statistics

Four fair coins are repeatedly tossed simultaneously until all four show the same face. What
is the probability that this occurs on the fourth toss?

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Calculate the probability of this happening on a single toss, and then calculate the chance of that not happening for the first 3 tosses, followed by it happening on the fourth.